# different coefficients in ARX(1) and ln. regression with lagged y

Tags: regression, time-series

According to the theory ARX(1) is the same as a linear regression with a lagged y. For some reason the coefficients can be very different though.
Here is a simple dataset for demonstration purposes:

`y=c(3,4,6,3,3,5,7,8,5,7,3,2,5,7,4,3,5,6,8,4,3,5,6,3,2,5,6,7,8)
y.lag1=c(3,3,4,6,3,3,5,7,8,5,7,3,2,5,7,4,3,5,6,8,4,3,5,6,3,2,5,6,7)
x1=c(7,4,9,6,4,5,3,5,7,9,7,8,5,6,8,4,3,3,6,3,1,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,4)
x2=c(6,3,5,6,7,4,6,8,9,6,0,5,7,4,6,7,8,5,4,5,6,4,1,2,4,7,8,0,8)`

Fitting an ARX(1) model gives me the following coefficients:

`> arx.model=arima(y, xreg=data.frame(x1, x2), order=c(1,0,0), method="ML")`

`Coefficients:
        ar1  intercept      x1      x2
      0.331     3.6976  0.1967  0.0430`

Fitting a linear Regression with a lagged y variable gives me the following coefficients:

`> lm.model=lm(y~y.lag1+x1+x2)`

`Coefficients:
(Intercept)       y.lag1           x1           x2

    2.44489      0.31319      0.09048      0.10077`

I'm wondering why there is such a big difference in the coefficients.
I assume that the different estimation procedures (OLS in the linear regression and ML in ARX) do not cause such a big difference.
Does anyone know what causes the difference?

**Edit:**

This is how I understand the concept of a lagged y variable:

[image]

Instead of adding the number 3 to the first missing observation in y_(t-1) I now ignore the first row (as suggested in the comments). That means, I use the sample size T-1.
Using this logic I refitted the model:

`disign.matrix=data.frame(y.lag1=y[1:28], x1=x1[2:29], x2=x2[2:29])`
`lm.model=lm(y[2:29]~y.lag1+x1+x2, data=disign.matrix)`

and get the following coefficients:

`(Intercept)       y.lag1           x1           x2`

`2.4645            0.2722         0.1265       0.1106`

They are still quite different from the ARX coefficients. Any further suggestions?

Comment: At this point I think the question is really becoming off-topic as it's clearly about R not the general statistics. MLE and OLS should give the same parameter estimates in ARX model, the only reason they're not is something to do with R code and its packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARX(1) model that you are considering, that is,
$$
y_t = \theta_0 + \phi_1 y_t + \beta_1 x_t + w_t \tag{1}
$$
is not the same as a regression model
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + e_t \tag{2a}
$$
with errors $e_t$ following an autoregressive model
$$
e_t = \phi_1 e_t + w_t.  \tag{2b}
$$
An important difference is that for model (2), $y_t$ is only influenced only by the current value of $x_t$ whereas for model (1) $y_t$ is influenced by the current and all past values of $x_t$.

The `arima` function in R with covariates contained in the `xreg` argument fits models such as (2).

To fit ARIMAX models such as the above ARX(1) model use the `arimax` function in the `TSA` package.

In addition, `method="ML"` (maximum likelihood) is not the same as OLS equivalent to the conditional sum of square method for models with no MA part (`method="CSS"`) as the latter method ignores information contained in the first initial observations.  Methods based on the exact likelihood computes the probability of the first observations based on the stationary distribution of the process, via the Kalman filter applied to the state space representation of the model.  So this is another reason for the difference you see.

Answer (score 1):

If you line up the series right you certainly should get the same results in MLE and OLS estimations in terms of the coefficients of ARX(1) model.

I think in your case there's something funky that R `arima` function does with pre-sampling. It's the very first observation of the dependent variable. In MATLAB you either supply that observation with `Y0` parameter or MATLAB will back forecast it. I'll show you the code where I'm providing this value below. If I let MATLAB backforecast the first observation then OLS and ARIMA estimates will not match.

Here's how it works in MATLAB:

```
y=[3,4,6,3,3,5,7,8,5,7,3,2,5,7,4,3,5,6,8,4,3,5,6,3,2,5,6,7,8]';
x1=[7,4,9,6,4,5,3,5,7,9,7,8,5,6,8,4,3,3,6,3,1,4,5,3,4,5,6,7,4]';
x2=[6,3,5,6,7,4,6,8,9,6,0,5,7,4,6,7,8,5,4,5,6,4,1,2,4,7,8,0,8]';
X=[x1 x2];

model = arima(1,0,0);
fit = estimate(model,y(2:end),'X',X(2:end,:),'Y0',y(1))
```

With output

```
                              Standard          t     
 Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
 Constant        2.46451       1.69782        1.45157
    AR{1}       0.272167      0.233228        1.16695
    Beta1       0.126459      0.189871       0.666028
    Beta2       0.110629      0.136319       0.811544
 Variance        2.91062       1.76726        1.64696
```

Then we do OLS:

```
fitlm([y(1:end-1) X(2:end,:)],y(2:end))
```

and output:

```
Estimated Coefficients:
                   Estimate      SE        tStat     pValue 
                   ________    _______    _______    _______

    (Intercept)     2.4645      1.5453     1.5949    0.12383
    x1             0.27217     0.20217     1.3462     0.1908
    x2             0.12646     0.18162    0.69627    0.49295
    x3             0.11063      0.1483      0.746    0.46291
```

Comment: In addition to this reply, you must remove the first row of the data! see http://dspace.brunel.ac.uk/handle/2438/14135

Comment: hang on! lag looks okay, except the first one that is not important!

Comment: @Aksakal and TPArrow: Thanks for the quick response. Please check my edit above.